# how to update existing labels for specific GCP VM in NodeJs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i want to update the existing labels for specific instance in google cloud platform using nodeJs libraries but i am not able find the any module to update the labels in NodeJS. Really appreciate if anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  compute.instances.setlables() from [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). There is some example code [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels#authorization-scopes) (See the “Examples” section for NodeJS). You would need to send the request body as a parameter, you can consult it’s structure in [this section](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels#request-body).

There are 2 considerations to keep in mind:

1. As part of the request body, you need the current labels “labelFingerprint” which you can get from the [instance details](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get#authorization-scopes).
2. Previous labels will be overwritten, so make sure to include in the request any labels you want to preserve.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually i missed to mention that i am looking for same kind of solution using NodeJS libraries  provided by GCP. I don't want to use "googleapi" for the same. For example - @google-cloud/compute ->this library for starting/stoping vm so i need a this kind of library or any module which can set the labels for specific vm.

Comment: i just gone through vm.getMetadata and vm.setMetadata function. Labels are part of metadata and i think we can update labels using vm.setMetadata. I tried setting labels using this function but its not updating and even i passed current label fingerprints.

Comment: I don't think setting labels is supported in the gcp client library. I agree labels are some kind of metadata, but in GCP they are different concepts. [Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) are key-value pairs used to store information about an instance, for example, it's name or machine type. There is also custom metadata, which is useful to pass some fixed values to your instance or to setup startup scripts. [Labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) are also key-value pairs, but they are mainly used for reporting purposes.